# Writing a function in R to rbind new rows to dataframe

Tags: r, function, rbind

Write a function that allows me to enter in several parameters that are entered into a new row

I've written the function and it seems to work (at the end of the function I print the results), but for some reason my data frame never updates.  Maybe I'm overwriting the df in the wrong place?  I've read several related articles but still unsure what it isn't working.

```r
my_portfolio <- data.frame(
    stockname = 'AMZN',
    stock_price_time_of_purchase = 1500,
    shares_purchased = 3,
    date_purchased = as.Date('2018-03-23'),
    stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)
```

```r
add_to_portfolio <- function(stockname,
                             stock_price_time_of_purchase,
                             shares_purchased,
                             date_purchased) {

    my_portfolio <- rbind(
        my_portfolio,
        data.frame(
            stockname,
            stock_price_time_of_purchase,
            shares_purchased,
            date_purchased,
            stringsAsFactors = FALSE
        )
    )

    print(my_portfolio)

}
```

```r
add_to_portfolio(
    'MO',         #stockname
    50,           #price
    10,           #shares
    '2018-01-23'  #date purchased
)
```

No error message.  My function runs and prints out a dataframe that has the new row included.  But when I look at the object in my environment it only contains the original row

Comment: Don't use `print`. Printing doesn't assign to the Globalenv.

Comment: Too long to write in a comment, don't want to add an answer. Just wrap your result in `assign` or something else that assigns to the Global env.

Comment: Add `return(my_portfolio)` as the last line of the function and then you need to assign the returned value back to the gobal value `my_portfilio <- add_to_portfolio(...)`